# When to use been instead of was?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, irregular-forms

In this sentence

> ... but I’d rather focus on the future rather than **what's been**

we see "been" at the end, I would never think to make it that way, I would put "was".

> ... but I’d rather focus on the future rather than **what was**

Please explain?

[Source.](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/henry-cavill-doesnt-think-zack-snyder-cut-justice-league-will-make-difference-exclusive-112542828.html?guccounter=1)

Comment: What does the “‘s” in “what’s” represent in your sentence?

Comment: "what has was" is not an acceptable English phrase.

Comment: @ColleenV it's not my, I saw it on article on the web. I don't know.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to explain where you found the sentence, and what you found when you tried to answer your question before posting here. See this post for some good advice for adding enough detail to your questions: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161 More explanation of why you’re asking and what you already know will help you get good answers (and maybe some upvotes!)

Comment: I've edited to hopefully clarify your question, as it's a good one.  Actually both "what has been" and "what was" work in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **what's been** because it's using the [present perfect tense](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/).

*what's been* is the same as **what has been**.

*has been* is the present perfect tense, which is made with *to have* + the past participle of a verb, and [the past participle of *to be* is *been*.](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-be.html)  *What has was* doesn't make any sense, like DrMoishe Pippik says, because *was* is not the past participle of *to be*, and "has was" isn't correct conjugation.

What might be confusing you is that you could also say

> I’d rather focus on the future rather than what **was**.

That is using the simple past *was* rather than the present perfect *has been*.

Comment: @standgon so, `what was` is correct. If `been` is `past participle` then what about was - what kind of past is it ?

Comment: @RS - *was* is the [simple past](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/).